# Alternative to Java Selenium Web tools

Tags: java, php, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Java code, which implements the Selenium web driver. Whenever this code is run, it will open a website, enter some info into a text area and then submit it. As of right now it works as I want it to, although there is one problem. I am not a big fan of the fact that I am reliable on the web driver, which the user of the app has. Meaning if the user has Safari, the web driver has to be for Safari and if the user has Chrome the web driver has to be for Chrome etc. 
So with this in mind I was wondering if there is an alternative to my code, which does exactly the same. But which doesn't rely on the web driver and will just do the same action in whatever browser the user has. 
Note I am the one who will create the website and back end php of which the Java app has to connect to. So I wont mind it, if I have to change something on that site, to make an alternative work. 
I have added both my Java/Selenium and html/php script to make sure everything is listed.

### Java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class uOnline {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

          driver.get("https://mywebsite.com");

          WebElement textBoxElement = driver.findElement(By.name("Send"));

          textBoxElement.sendKeys("testing testing #1");

          textBoxElement.submit();

          driver.close();

    }

}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="saveInfo.php" method="POST" id="sInfoForm">

  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="Send"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php

$file = 'uploads/file.txt';

$text = $_POST['Send'];

file_put_contents($file, $text . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

### UPDATE

After being informed of the JBrowserDriver I have tried using it, only issue is that it doesn't submit anything and it doesn't get any errors. Thus making it a bit hard for me to know what is wrong.

Currently it looks as seen below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Settings;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Timezone;

public class uOnline {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().
          timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).build());

        driver.get("https://mywebsite.com");

        WebElement textBoxElement = driver.findElement(By.name("Send"));

        textBoxElement.sendKeys("testing JBrowser driver");

        textBoxElement.submit();

        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried curl....curl doesn't depend on any webdriver...  https://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar I appreciate the feedback, I have just looked at the website. Is it used inside Java or is it an independent language? It seems like it might work, I just need to find some tutorial for it as I have never worked with it before.

Comment: curl can be used as bash command...i am not sure if there is exhaustive tutorials...but i am sure a bit of google search might definitely lead something..

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Alright, I will look further into it and use it in case I cant find another Java option. Never the less, your input is very much appreciated.

Comment: @fkrottenkirk you can try to use embedded browser like JBrowserDriver.

Comment: @AldoSuwandi I appreciate the input, is it like a generic driver? Like it will work for whatever browser is used? Also just to make sure I have understood it correctly, it is implemented and used along with the Selenium right?

Comment: @fkrottenkirk well actually it's an embedded browser, so it's not using any browser installed in your system ( you won't see any browser popping up when you run the test). And yes, it supports all selenium (webdriver) feature.

Comment: @AldoSuwandi I appreciate the info, I have tried to edit my Java project. But for some reason it doesn't work properly, I have edited the question with code and explanation if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: @AldoSuwandi I have fixed it and it works, a bit slow, but it definitely works. Thank you very much. In case you want to, you could make your comment an answer, for me to be able to accept it.